# Combinations problem with a group and 2 subgroups

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

From 50 school students we have to choose 6 students that will dance in a school play and 4 students that will be the actors in the play.
How many different combinations of dancers and actors can we make?

I wrote $\dfrac{50!}{6!4!}$. Am I right? Or is it $C(50,6)·C(44,4)$?

It's something that confuses ME.

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)

Comment: An observation: $\dfrac{50!}{6!4!}$ is a HUGE number, over $10^{60}$. There are a lot of ways of choosing students to dance and act, but surely not that many!

Comment: Thank you very much for the useful observation! So the total of all different combinations is C(50,6)*C(44,4)?

Comment: Yes, that's correct. I'll write some details in an answer.